# How to store column name as first row in datatable?

Tags: c#

```
Title| 11/09/2015 | 23/01/2015
----  -------------  ----------------
 A        1             12  
 B        1             13
```

I want to store the column name as `Datarow` in `DataTable`.

Tried :

```
DataRow firstRow = table.NewRow();
for (var i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
{        
     firstRow[i] = header.Rows[0][i].ToString();
}
table.Rows.InsertAt(firstRow, 0);
```

Error:

> Incorrect String 11/09/2015 need double.

Expected Output:

```
 Title| 11/09/2015 | 23/01/2015
----  -------------  ----------------
Title   11/09/2015   23/01/2015
 A        1             12  
 B        1             13
```

Comment: Try for (var i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count - 1; i++) and declare your column as string so it can hold any value

Comment: Yes tried , i know , the problem in casting , DataRow doesnot accept column name as string i guess :)

Comment: As your table has columns of different types, you simply cannot do this. What is the need to do this? It sounds senseless.

Comment: You can use [`DataColumn.ColumnName property`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.columnname.aspx). Check [How do I get column names to print in this C# program?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2557937/447156) as well.

Comment: Can i ask why you want to add the columns to the first `DataRow`? You have the informations already in the table.

Comment: yeah i know @yeldar i dont know how to do that that's why i posted :)

Comment: Hey @tim it is the requirement :(

Comment: @vinodh: your expected output is not what you describe. I thought you want the column-names in the first row. Can you explain better what you want? Where do you get that error?

Comment: Sorry for Confusion @Tim . I need first row as my columnname .. Thats it. But problem is format , Datarow couldn't understand the dateformat . Even i tried to change to string i unable store the Columnname as row.

Comment: First row as your column name? You know that a `DataRow` can have n-field values. So why do you use singular " column name" instead of " column names"?

Comment: @vinodh: now i understand the problem. The second and third columns are `double`-columns. Of course you can'd add values like `11/09/2015`. How would you want to convert that to double? You etiehr have to tell us how you want toconvert it or use `String` as DataColumn-type

Comment: Exactly @TIm .. String is fine

Comment: @vinodh: then go with the third approach in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now i understand the problem. The second and third columns are `double`-columns. Of course you can'd add values like `11/09/2015`. How would you want to convert that to double? You either have to tell us how you want to convert it or use `String` as `DataColumn`-type.

One option would be to use `DateTime.ToOADate()` which is the ole automation date:

```
DataRow firstRow = table.NewRow();
for (var i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    string colName = table.Columns[i].ColumnName;
    DateTime dt;
    double d;
    if(DateTime.TryParse(colName, out dt))
        firstRow.SetField(i, dt.ToOADate());
    else if(double.TryParse(colName, out d))
        firstRow.SetField(i, d);
}
table.Rows.InsertAt(firstRow, 0);
```

Another way would be to check the column-type:

```
DataRow firstRow = table.NewRow();
for (var i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    DataColumn col = table.Columns[i];
    if (col.DataType == typeof(string))
    {
        firstRow.SetField(i, col.ColumnName);
    }
    else if (col.DataType == typeof(DateTime))
    {
        DateTime dt;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(col.ColumnName, out dt))
            firstRow.SetField(i, dt);
    }
    else if (col.DataType == typeof(double))
    {
        double d;
        if (double.TryParse(col.ColumnName, out d))
            firstRow.SetField(i, d);
    }
}
table.Rows.InsertAt(firstRow, 0);
```

But this natural approach would not solve your issue since you have a `DateTime` value that has to be converted to a `double`.

---

The third and easiest approach would be use use `String` as column-type.

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Title");
table.Columns.Add("11/09/2015"); // string is default
table.Columns.Add("23/01/2015");
DataRow firstRow = table.NewRow();
for (var i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    string colName = table.Columns[i].ColumnName;
    firstRow.SetField(i, colName);
}
table.Rows.InsertAt(firstRow, 0);
```

That works always.

Comment: i hope it will works, i miss the setField property... :) I ll check

Comment: @vinodh: `SetField` is just another method to assign a value. You could also use firstRow[i] = new value. The difference is that `SetField` also supports nullable types.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer.. i can debug now ... final question           **Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store <1/2/2015> in 1/2/2015 Column.  Expected type is Double.**                                     Its giving this error i can debug... but you can easily found the error thats y i posted here.

Comment: @vinodh: with what approach? Since expected type is double i think you haven't used the third. How do you create the table and the columns?

Comment: second and third  approach

Comment: @vinodh: How do you create the table? The last way uses `string` as column-type, so it's not clear how it can expect double. The second approach also checks if the column-type mateches the value, so if it can't be parsed it will use `DBNull.Value`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97603/discussion-between-vinodh-and-tim-schmelter).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
DataRow dr = table.NewRow();
foreach (DataColumn dc in table.Columns)
 {

  dr[dc] = dc.ColumnName;

 }
table.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
```

Comment: I thought that also, but look at his expected output.

Comment: I tried this i guess this would produce expected output.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Normally it should work but in someways we have problem in column Datatype. +1 for right answer... but @tim explained good and futuristic way that's why accepted his answer.

Comment: Yes he is a genius guy his asnwer is much clearer than mine.