# Resolve string to a property of an object

Tags: c#

I have a database table in SQL Server and I need to configure a .NET application to use some of the data in this table, this data is used in a SOAP API call.

For example, the table has these columns

> > FirstName | LastName | EmailAddress

The values in these columns need to map to certain fields in the API call. This configuration must be flexible, so I cannot just assign FirstName to apiobject.firstname, for example.

Is there a way to derive a string to a property of an object?

For example, for FirstName, would it be possible to resolve it to object.Firstname = value but not doing it like this

```
if(column == "FirstName")
{
    ApiObject.FirstName = columnValue
}
```

Rather I would want to do something like

```
ApiObject.[somehow-resolve-which-field] = columnValue
```

Does anyone know what I am on about?

Comment: You can use `dynamic` property for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you does not have notation of this class and you simply want to create an object with required properties - the right way is to use `dynamic`, as it noted in other answers.

If you already have a class, for example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

You can do what you want with [`reflection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/f7ykdhsy(v=vs.110).aspx) as following:

```
var myObject = new MyClass();
var prop = myObject.GetType().GetProperty(column);
prop.SetValue(myObject, columnValue);
```

Where `column` and `columnValue` are from your example. Note that `column` should be of `string` type and `columnValue` should match the type of property.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood you need an object which you don't know how many properties have it and what are these properties. For this situations there is `dynamic` keyword in `c#`. You can initialize your `ApiObject` as `dynamic`

```
dynamic ApiObject = new ExpandoObject();
```

then you can set properties of this object as following:

```
ApiObject.YourProperty=columnValue;
```

more details: [About ExpandoObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.100).aspx)

**UPDATE** 
if you want to know which column is this, there is a `ColumnName` of `DataTable` of `System.Data` namespace. There are some issues for getting columns of table in `c#`. One of them is:
[How do I get column names to print in this C# program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557937/how-do-i-get-column-names-to-print-in-this-c-sharp-program)

Comment: Right, but my issue is how to know which property to set?