# Row does not exist in current context while printing the Column name along with each row value.?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datatable, datarow

i am trying to print Datatable column name along with there values but i am getting error 
 **Row does not exist in current context** 
 my code below.have tried the solution of [How do I get column names to print in this C# program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557937/how-do-i-get-column-names-to-print-in-this-c-sharp-program) but not working

```
foreach (DataRow row in dtfinal.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn col in dtfinal.Columns)

               Console.WriteLine(col.ColumnName);
            Console.WriteLine(row[col]); //error coming here

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do that like this

```
foreach (DataRow row in dtfinal.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataColumn column in dtfinal.Columns)
    {
        Console.Write("Item: ");
        Console.Write(column.ColumnName);
        Console.Write(" ");
        Console.WriteLine(row[column]);
    }
}
```

Comment: you are missing   { } in foreach of data column

Comment: put it there and please write the error that you are getting

Comment: if its worked for you then mark it as answer So that other may see it worked for you and you got  your solution thanks